# How to build set of indices to reference an array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, broadcasting

If I have:

```
x = np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

And I would like to create:

```
y = np.asarray([1,4,5])
```

In order to do this, I built an array as follows:

```
inds = np.asarray([[0,0],[1,1],[2,0]])
```

And I passed it to `x` as follows:

```
y = x[inds]
```

---

---

This does not yield the elements indexed by the rows in `inds`.  How do I achieve this functionality in either this fashion, or a fashion very similar to this?

Comment: `x[tuple(inds.T)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [*advanced indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) for; Extract the row index and column index into two separate arrays and use them to subset the array:

```
x[inds[:,0], inds[:,1]]
# array([1, 4, 5])
```

​